# Counting walks on colored graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for help counting distinct walks on a proper vertex coloring of a graph.  To be more specific, let's consider an odd cycle of order greater than 3 that has been properly 3-colored.

So, for example, we could color $C_9$ by alternating $r,g,b$ as we moved clockwise around the vertices. Every vertex in $C_9$ is adjacent to two vertices.  With this coloring, every vertex is adjacent to two distinct colors.  The result would be that for any positive integer $k$ there are $(3)(2^{k-1})$ walks on $k$ colored vertices.  Alternatively, we could color one vertex $r$ and then alternate $g,b$ on the others. Now, not every vertex is adjacent to two distinct colors.  For a given $k$, it seems like there should be a formula for the number of walks (on $k$ colored vertices) as a function of the number of vertices that are adjacent to two distinct colors.  However, I am having trouble constructing and proving such a formula.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "distinct walks" in this context? That does that have to do with coloring?

Comment: I am interested in the walks on the colors.  So if $f$ is a coloring of $V(G)$, I am interested in counting distinct  $f(v_1)f(v_2)..f(v_k)$ where $v_1v_2...v_k$ is a walk on $G$.

Comment: Can you explain your $3*2^{k−1}$ walks on k 3-colored vertices formula?  At least at k=1 and k=2 the numbers appear to be twice as large; *e.g* {br, bg, gr, gb, rg, rb} at k=1, and {gbg, grg, gbr, grb, *etc*} at k=2.

Comment: Here, $k$ is the number of vertices, not the number of edges.  So, when $k=2$, you have $\{br,bg,gr,gb,rg,rb\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The asymptotic growth constant will be dependent on the specific colouring.

For example, suppose $n=5$ and the colouring is $01012$ (with $d=3$), then $W_k$ counts the walks that exclude the sequences $2012$ and $2102$.
In this case, asymptotically, $W_k$ grows by a factor of about $1.82462$ (in comparison, $2^{3/5}\approx 1.51572$).

Similarly, if $n=7$ and the colouring is $0101012$ (again $d=3$), then $W_k$ counts the walks that exclude the sequences $2012$, $2102$, $201012$ and $210102$.
In this case, asymptotically, $W_k$ grows by a factor of about $1.76540$ (whereas $2^{3/7}\approx 1.34590$).

In fact, the growth factor is nearly always greater than $2^{d/n}$ because even a colouring with minimal $d$ does not exclude many of the possible coloured walks.

As another example, if the colouring is $0101\dots 0121$ (with $d=2$ and even $n$), then $02$ and $20$ are excluded (each walk alternating between $1$ and either $0$ or $2$) giving
$$
W_k\;=\;2^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}+2^{\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}
$$
with a growth factor of $\sqrt{2}$. In this case the result is independent of $n$ (and hence independent of $d/n$).

Comment: Suppose 0101...012 colouring.  If $n>5$, isn't 201012 also excluded?

Comment: Yes, correction added.

Comment: Again suppose odd $n$ and 0101...012 colouring.  If $n=7$, 20101012 is not excluded, but for $n>7$ it is.  For $n>9$, 2010101012 is excluded, etc.  I guess I am not convinced the number is independent of $n$.  How did you calculate 1.82462?

Comment: Apologies (too quick to generalise). Will correct again.

Comment: I calculated the numeric growth factors by using _Mathematica_ to (a) generate the $W_k$, (b) find the linear difference equation, and (c) numerically find the roots of the resultant "characteristic polynomial". For the $C_5$ example, the polynomial is $x^4 - x^3 - 2 x^2 + 2 x - 2 = 0$; for the $C_7$ example, it is $x^6 - x^5 - 2 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 2 x^2 + 2 x - 2 = 0$ (it looks like there's a pattern there).

Comment: Thank you again David.  I have another follow up question, but I will post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t possible to enumerate these walks using only the number of vertices which are adjacent to $2$ distinct colours.

Consider two $4$-coloured copies of $C_6$, one coloured *red*, *yellow*, *red*, *yellow*, *green*, *blue* (or $010123$) and the other coloured *red*, *yellow*, *green*, *yellow*, *red*, *blue* (or $012103$).

Both cycles have the same number of vertices of each colour and the same number ($4$) of vertices that are adjacent to $2$ distinct colours, but the first has $8$ distinct $2$-walks while the second has only $6$ distinct $2$-walks.

Even the ‘adjacency lists’ are not sufficient:

Consider two $5$-coloured copies of $C_7$, one coloured $0 1 0 2 1 3 4$ and the other coloured $0 2 0 1 3 4 1$. They both have the same number of vertices of each colour and the same adjacency list: $(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)$, but the former has  $12$ distinct $2$-walks while the latter has only $10$ distinct $2$-walks.

Comment: What if we restrict to 3-colorings of odd cycles?  Perhaps we can find an asymptotic formula.  Say, that for large $k$, there are approximately $m2^{ck/d}$ walks where $m$, $c$ and $d$ are constants, and I suspect $c/d$ is a function of the number of vertices that are adjacent to 2 distinct colours.

Comment: I would have thought that an asymptotic formulae would be easy to determine, but restricting the problem to 3-colourings of odd cycles doesn't enable the original question to be solved. The following 2 colourings of a 9-cycle - $0 1 0 1 0 2 0 1 2$ and
$0 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 2$ - have different numbers of 4-walks.

Comment: Thank you David.  If we consider a proper 3-coloring of an odd cycle $C_n$.  Is the asymptotic formula simply $\approx m2^{\frac{dk}{n}}$ where $m$ is some constant and $d$ is the number of vertices adjacent to 2 distinct colors?

Comment: I think it may be rather more complex than that, and will depend on the relationship between $d$, $k$ and $n$. In fact, I'm thinking that we may see phase change behaviour. For example, if $d/n$ is large enough for there to be a run of $2k+1$ adjacent vertices that are all adjacent to 2 distinct colours (e.g. _rgbrgb..._), then all $3\times 2^{k-1}$ coloured walks are possible.

Comment: Let's consider a precise limit as $k \to \infty$.  Suppose we fix an odd $n$, fix a proper 3-coloring of $C_n$.  Let $d$ be the number of vertices adjacent to 2 colors.  Let $W_k$ be the number of walks on $k$ coloured vertices.  Is then, $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\log(W_k)}{k}=\frac{d}{n} \log 2$?